# Is the Game Engines Coodinate System different?

Tags: game-engine

I tried to rotate an object around its z-axis, by using a motion actuator with z-rotation (blue axis in screen) but it rotates around the y-axis (green).

Are y and z-axis for some reasons swaped in the BGE?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - Suzanne (the monkey) has her Z axis pointing out from her face, and the Motion actuator defaults to use local coordinates. Either:

- Apply rotation to the mesh (*<kbd>Object</kbd>><kbd>Apply</kbd>><kbd>Rotation</kbd>*), or
- Switch the actuator to world coordinates (press the *<kbd>L</kbd>* toggle button on the right of the *Rot* row).