# Setting A Circle's Rotation From A Changing Number in the BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, transforms

I have a timer that counts from 82 to -82 and back.
And I have a circle that should rotate (x rotation) from 82 to -82 and back.

How can I assign the timer number to the x rotation number of the circle?

My code so far is:

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

circle = cont.owner

matrix_rotation = circle.worldOrientation

euler_rotation = matrix_rotation.to_euler()

degrees_rotation = [math.degrees(a) for a in euler_rotation]

circleRotation = int(degrees_rotation[1])
```

Now I want to reverse the steps but don't know how to do it. The timer is driven by the system time and the circle should spin accordingly (it is kind of a skybox).

Answer (score 2):

All your need to do is take your timer's output (the *timer* var in my script), convert it to radians and then insert it in the object rotation vector.

```
import bge
import math

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
circle = cont.owner

x = math.radians(timmer)
circle.worldOrientation = (x, 0.0, 0.0)
```

The reason for the math.radians() conversion is [worldOrientation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldOrientation) is a vector storing the rotation for the X, Y and Z axes in radians.

---

As a side note, a much simpler way to get the rotation of a object in degrees  is with these two lines. I used the same variable names you did to make it easier to see where it would fit in.

```
euler_rotation = circle.worldOrientation.to_euler()
circleRotation = math.degrees(euler_rotation[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help David! I've tried it, however the circle always seems to spin around a different axis as I want it to... If I hook up a simple motion actuator and let it rotate in the x axis all is fine. There must be a mistake somewhere...? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sputi First [apply](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2563/2217) the rotation of your circle. Then try running the game again.

Comment: Applying the rotation did the trick. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Uhh.. still a problem: the circle doesn't make a 360 degrees spin but only 180 and then goes all the same way back to 0 again. Is there a way to tell the circle to make the full spin instead of two half spins?

Comment: Ok that full spin works now, was a mistake in my part, but the circle now does a full 360 and then rotates the same way back instead of keeping on rotating the same direction... any ideas?